# Elements values empties parsing XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

The xml file to parse https://webassos.com/uploads/results/ffnex_performances_54059.xml

```
<?php
$file = 'https://webassos.com/uploads/results/ffnex_performances_54059.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
print_r($xml);
?>
```

Return a well formated array with XML elements and attributes

```
<?php
$meeting = $xml->MEET;
print_r($meeting);
?>
```

Return an empty object.

Same result with a DOM document and trying to get element MEET by tagName.

Why this method that I usually use does not work in this case, please?

Comment: you can just use `SimpleXML`, seen the actual xml, there are multiple `<MEET>` nodes, you'll need a `foreach` for that

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] - a small section of XML which demonstrates the problem, in the question itself, rather than linking to your full document.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your structure You have a child node meets and there you find meet

```
var_dump($xml->MEETS->MEET);
```

Comment: That's of course. Thank you for your attention, mine was on standby ...